# SQL data error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL query that's returning this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Here's the query :

```
POQuery = "SELECT Distinct PurchaseOrders.POrderID, PurchaseOrders.VendorName, PurchaseOrderDetail.ArrDate "
          + "FROM PurchaseOrders "
          + "FULL JOIN PurchaseOrderDetail ON PurchaseOrders.POrderID = PurchaseOrderDetail.POrderID "
          + "WHERE PurchaseOrders.Buyer = @Buyer and ArrDate >= convert(DateTime, '"
          + datePickerStart.Value.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") + "') and ArrDate <= convert(DateTime, '"
          + datePickerEnd.Value.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") + "')";
```

I'm using the datepicker to pick dates.

Comment: Come on - a little more effort formatting the question

Comment: sry im new to this and it was kind of an emergency situation.

Comment: Post the value for POQuery - exactly what is being sent to SQL

Comment: datePickerStart.Value.ToString = 1/22/2016 9:14:44 AM  && datePickerEnd.Value.ToString has the same value

Comment: You really should use parameters, then you wouldn't need to convert the `DateTime` to a string, just to convert it back to a date in SQL.

Comment: All of POQuery please

Comment: that's all of the query

Comment: As already said: use parameters. Do you want to see why your **date format** is wrong? Type that query in management studio...

Comment: That is the code not the query.  What is the value of POQuery.  If you don't want me to look at it fine.

Comment: @Frisbee sry i didnt get ur question.. POQuery is just a variable i used to assign the query to. which value?

Comment: Yes POQuery is a variable and it will have a value     Debug.WriteLint(POQuery)

Comment: Your error is not reproducible.  I get no error when I execute this:  `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '1/22/2016 9:14:44 AM')`  You must be doing something else that you're not telling us.

Comment: @TabAlleman, try this with a `SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;` before :-) Look at my answer, I just added some lines to show this...

Comment: @Shnugo I got the issue resolved. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is culture related... You should never rely on culture specific date-time formats! Otherwise you'd have to tell the T-SQL `CONVERT` function the specific format (which should be 101 in your case)...

Just try this:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '1/22/2016 9:14:44 AM'); --works
GO
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '1/22/2016 9:14:44 AM'); --error
GO
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '1/22/2016 9:14:44 AM',101); --works
```

Best is to use ISO8601 `2016-01-22T18:59:00`

or one of the ODBC formats which is

```
{d'2016-01-22'}
{t'18:59:00'}
{ts'2016-01-22 18:59:00'}
```

Doing so, you don't even have to call convert...

And - as others have pointed out - you should use parameters rather than concatenated strings...

Comment: Also, `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss` or `yyyymmdd` (without dashes) are also 100% reliable.

Comment: @ErikE Your are right - it's a matter of preference... I dislike the "naked number" date format as it could be mistaken as a number...