# sql date behaviour

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I've noticed some odd behaviour in converting string to date and date time formats... See below:

```
select datename(M,'2016-02-04')
select datename(M,'2016-02-04 14:42:26')

SELECT datename(M,Cast('2016-02-04' as Date))
SELECT datename(M,CAST('2016-02-04 14:42:26' as DateTime))

SELECT Cast('2016-02-04' as Date)
SELECT CAST('2016-02-04 14:42:26' as DateTime)
SELECT CAST('2016-02-04 14:42:26' as SmallDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(DateTime,'2016-02-04 14:42:26')
```

Results:

```
February
February
February
April
2016-02-04
2016-04-02 14:42:26.000
2016-04-02 14:42:26.000
```

Can anyone explain why it's converting the datetime values to America format and not the default which is British? I've ran this again explicitly setting the date format to ymd and it then works correctly??? Any ideas anyone?

```
 select * 
 from sys.syslanguages  
 where Name = @@LANGUAGE
```

Output of above query in Trassposed format for better viewing.

```
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|   langid    | 23                                                         |
| dateformat  | dmy                                                        |
| datefirst   | 1                                                          |
| upgrade     | 0                                                          |
| name        | British                                                    |
| alias       | British English                                            |
| months      | January,February,March,April,May,June,July,                |
|             | August,September,October,November,December                 |
| shortmonths | Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec            |
| days        | Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday   |
| lcid        | 2057                                                       |
| msglangid   | 1033                                                       |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your problem is somewhat related to this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818796/error-converting-string-to-datetime-due-to-locale - take a look if it could help you solve your problem.

Comment: That's why I **never** use culture depending formats... I posted some save alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34953123/5089204

Comment: Check [`DATETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) for proper locale neutral formats. Use `YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]]` or `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]`

Comment: @StoneleighDev why are you using text instead of date types at all? If you used `date` or `datetime` fields and parameters you could avoid all conversion issues. That's much better than using eg safe literals or calling `PARSE` with a scecific culture

Comment: @Shnugo actually, if you could find the one, definite duplicate question so we don't have to repeat the same answers all the time.

Comment: @Shnugo such questions appear very frequently and there are a lot of duplicate answers that explain cultures, formats, the need to use types instead of strings etc. Some are (much) better than others though. They have become so many that it's very hard to find the good ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try YYYMMDD

```
select
  a = datename(M,'20160204')
, b = datename(M,'20160204 14:42:26')

, c= datename(M,Cast('20160204' as Date))
, d = datename(M,CAST('20160204 14:42:26' as DateTime))

, e = Cast('20160204' as Date)
, f = CAST('20160204 14:42:26' as DateTime)
, g = CAST('20160204 14:42:26' as SmallDateTime)
, h = CONVERT(DateTime,'20160204 14:42:26')
```

That is the safest of all date styles in SQL Server. 
YYYY-DD-MM does exist (darn it) and it can get confused for YYYY-MM-DD

The other thing to do is use CONVERT(datatype, value, style_number) if the stye number is included e.g. convert(date,'2016-02-04 04:05:06.007',121) then the conversion knows the sequence of YYYY MM DD date parts.

Comment: YYYYMMDD isn't "safest", it's the only standard date format. All others are culture specific. The only standard datetime format is ISO8601, ie `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.zzz`. There's no need to convert the ISO8601 format

Comment: And don't forget the ODBC formats (follow the link I posted in my comment above), they are my favourites. I do not take yours as "safest" as the naked date could be mistaken as number...

Comment: This is great, went a different way in the end using a function to convert the month number to month name.